# How to use `column-marker-1` with every buffer?

Tags: init-file

Question may be very dumb, but I can't find the answer on the web :

I have a command `C-u 80 M-x column-marker-1`, and I want it to be launched automatically on every buffer I open. What should I add to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` to do that ?

Here is where `column-marker-1` is defined : https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/column-marker.el

Answer (score 1):

The emacs wiki page at : https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColumnMarker

gives an example for a hook:

> Highlight column 80 in foo mode:
>
> ```
> (add-hook 'foo-mode-hook (lambda () (interactive) (column-marker-1 80)))
> ```

Comment: I don't understand how to use it exactly.
I was able to add it to major mode (such as `c-mode` or `emacs-lisp-mode`) but I would like to have this enabled everytime, and writing one line for every existing major mode seems pretty dirty.
I tried to add a hook to `column-number-mode`(which is a minor mode always enabled by `(setq column-number-mode t)`), but it did nothing.
I can add it to a self created minor mode (defined by `(define-minor-mode col80 "foobar")`,but I don't know how to automatically launch my minor mode (hence I'm just moving the problem).

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899949/is-there-an-emacs-hook-that-runs-after-every-buffer-is-created